# 2 Forms Closing and opening

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 Forms. At init of 1st form I have code:

```
public App_Index()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Hide();

            Authorization loginForm = new Authorization();
            loginForm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

And if I push on Close button [X] on Form2 — App_Index(Form1) Form do .Show(); But no code in Form2 about this. I want to close Form1 and Form2 if I push [X] on Form2. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you looking to exit the whole program or just close 2 forms by pressing the close button?

Comment: Are you looking to close form 1 when form 2 is closed?

Comment: Try Application.Exit(); in form Closing Event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? This closes the current form if the dialog is cancelled.

```
public App_Index()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Hide();

    Authorization loginForm = new Authorization();
    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle `FormClosing` event :

```
private void Authorization_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing )
    {
         Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this.  You can use loop through `Application.OpenForms` and close the forms you wish.  I would do this on the `Form_Closing` event of Form2:

```
    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if(f.Name == "Form1")
                f.Close();
        }
    }
```

You can also access the form directly within the OpenForms collection and close it:

```
Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Close()
```